# Why is the result of fork system call displayed in one cmd?

Tags: process, operating-system, fork

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int value = 5; 
int main(){
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

if(pid ==0){
    value+=15;
    printf("CHILD: value = %d\n",value);
    return 0;
}
else if(pid>0){
    wait(NULL);
    printf("PARENT: value = %d",value);
    return 0;
}
    
}
```

The execution result of this code is as follows:

```
CHILD: value = 20                                                                                       
PARENT: value = 5
```

Then, in this process, two compilation processes took place, and it was understood that the first code and the code copied by the fork were each executed.

But why aren't there two cmd windows, but two result values ​​in one window? I want to find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the cmd windows has a different process than your program.

Once your program is started, it creates a new process, that runs on the cmd. When the fork happens, it will create a new process running on the same window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand. Then, as I mentioned above, the contents are the same, but can I understand that different executable files are each compiled in one cmd window?